# Как из главого потока определить состояние дополнительных потоков?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

Имеется главная форма с кнопкой, которая запускает и останавливает дополнительный поток:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Assigned(MyThread) then
    begin
      Button1.Enabled := False;
      MyThread.Terminate;
    end
  else
    begin
      Button1.Caption := 'STOP';
      MyThread := TMyThread.Create(True);
      MyThread.Priority := tpLower;
      MyThread.OnTerminate := OnTerm;
      MyThread.FreeOnTerminate := True;
      MyThread.Start;
    end;
end;

procedure TForm1.OnTerm(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MyThread := nil;
  Button1.Enabled := True;
  Button1.Caption := 'START'
end;
```

Сам дополнительный поток упрощенно выглядит так:

```
procedure TMyThread.Execute;
var
  i: Byte;
begin
  repeat
    for i := 1 to 4 do
      begin
        Sleep(1000);
        Synchronize(
          procedure
            begin
               Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add('Updated '+IntToStr(i));
            end
           );
      end;
  until Terminated;
end;
```

Как при закрытии главной формы `TForm1.FormClose` проверить состояние потока и если он запущен дать ему завершить свой цикл?

Comment: WaitForSingleObject, например. Но это если у вас handle потока есть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если готовы ждать бесконечно, то вот так:

```
if Assigned(MyThread) then begin
    MyThread.Terminate;
    MyThread.WaitFor;    
end;
```

Если нужно встроить лимит на ожидание, то вот так:

```
  var
    VHandle: THandle;
  ...
  if Assigned(MyThread) then begin
    VHandle := MyThread.Handle;  
    MyThread.Terminate;
    while WaitForSingleObject(VHandle, 100) = WAIT_TIMEOUT do begin
      Application.ProcessMessages;
      // тут можно выйти из цикла, по какому-либо условию
      // например, если прошло 5 сек. с начала цикла
    end;
  end;
```

Comment: `MyThread.WaitFor` при `MyThread.FreeOnTerminate := True` вываливает ошибку. Если же создавать поток с `MyThread.FreeOnTerminate := False` то при остановке потока кнопкой, в нашем случае возникает протечка памяти.

Comment: WaitForSingleObject(VHandle, 100) так же не выход, так как пример реализации Execute потока у меня условный, и лимит на ожидание предусмотреть невозможно

Comment: @HeathRow не понял, чем не подходит WaitForSingleObject? Там ничего принудительно предусматривать не нужно - цикл завершится в любом случае, при уничтожении потока. Но вот если он у вас будет что-то очень долго делать, пользователю просто надоест ждать закрытия программы, вот на этот случай и есть возможность экстренного прерывания цикла.

Comment: @ zed пардон, это действительно работает. Единственное у меня вопрос, в не возникнет ли AV при условии если в течении 100мс, указанных в параметре WaitForSingleObject, доп. поток будет уничтожен и VHandle будет указывать на уже несуществующий объект?

Comment: @HeathRow Если поток будет уничтожен в те 100 мс, то функция вернёт `WAIT_OBJECT_0`, если же он будет уничтожен до входа в эту функцию, то она вернёт `WAIT_FAILED`. Т.е. когда бы поток ни был уничтожен, цикл прервётся и никаких AV не будет.